# AWK get attribute value from XML element

Tags: xml, awk

Hello everyone I am trying to use AWK to extract the `version=` value from `pkg-info` from an XML file.

I would like to just do something like:

```
cat file_below.txt | awk some_commands
```

using the data below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<pkg-info overwrite-permissions="true" relocatable="false" identifier="com.application.something" version="1.2.3" format-version="2" generator-version="ABC" install-location="/Applications" auth="root">
</pkg-info>
```

The desired output would be:

```
1.2.3
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming no newlines within tag

```
gawk/mawk/mawk2 'BEGIN { FS = "version=\"" } /^[<]pkg-info/ {

    print substr($2, 1, index($2, "\"") -1 ); exit; }'
```

version to handle random \n

```
gawk/mawk/mawk2 'BEGIN { FS="version=\"" } (NF > 1) { 
       
    if (seen++) { print substr($2,1,index($2, "\"")-1); exit; } }'
```

This will skip the first time it sees version, at the initial xml tag. second time it prints the version number then exits. this code does not need to make assumptions regarding how version numbers are formatted, other than being double quoted.

version to account for pkg-info being all over the place :

```
gawk/mawk/mawk2 'BEGIN { RS = "^$"; FS = "([<]pkg-info|[\/]pkg-info[>])";
   
   } match($2, /version=[^ ]+/) {

       print substr($2, RSTART + 9, RLENGTH - 10); exit; }'
```

Just have it read in the whole XML file, not attempting to split things along NL.  Then when you enforce FS exactly being the opening and close tags of it, then $2 must be the first occurrence of such a tag.

Comment: This actually outputs `1.0` from `<?xml version="1.0" ...` in the first line. Suggest `awk '/<pkg-info/ && match($0, /version=[^ ]+/) { ...`

Comment: thanks David =) i've incorporated your suggested changes

Comment: Good deal. Works like a champ.

Comment: Does not work if the XML has any `\n` between `pkg-info` and `version=`

Comment: @dawg : created new variant to account for your feedback. does it work ?

Comment: For the second example but not the third example in my answer. The problem with `"version=\""` as `FS` is you have multiple `version="` in that small bit of XML. The third example is all the XML on a single line and now your target ends up in `$3` instead of `$2`. You will play whack-a-mole trying to nail them all down in a reliable fashion with splitting and regex. It is simply not reliable. Use a parser is the answer. There are awk based parsers, but you may as well use a C based one (expat or libxml are most common) which all three of my examples use.

Comment: @dawg : what about if first time it sees version, use sub(FS, "") to cleanse it away.

i mean XML parsers do have its use, but given the simplicity of the item attempted to be retrieved in question, so near the top of it. wouldn't a full XML parser, in any platform, be slightly overkill ?

Comment: Also keep in mind that since these are XML element attributes, the closing tag for `<pkg-info` can be either `</pkg-info>` or `/>` and that the data can be on an arbitrary set of lines and that the `<pkg-info attributes </pkg-info>` can be on the same line as other unrelated XML elements.

Comment: @dawg : that's fine. my second edition of the script doesn't bother even checking pkg-info anymore, under the assumption that the version= is the 2nd time it appears. unless the XML is far more complex than what's shown. another method is detecting pkg-info opening first. continuously scan (horizontally and across rows) until first instance of version=. then print and exit.

Comment: @dawg : made a 3rd version. hopefully this will finally account for all the quirkiness of XML.

Comment: i wrote it like that only to be able to be more portable across awk variants. it can be MUCH simpler if gensub( ) or match( )-with-array are used instead. can't guarantee POSIX compliance though.

Answer (score 3):

A simple way is to use `sed` to locate the line beginning `"<pkg-info..."` and then isolating the version with a substitution capturing the version and reinserting as a backreference, e.g.

```
sed -E -n '/^<pkg-info/s/^.*[ ]version="([^"]+)".*$/\1/p' file
```

Where `-E` specifies extended regex and `-n` suppresses normal output of pattern space, and:

- `/^<pkg-info/` locates the line beginning with `"<pkg-info"`, then the normal
- `s/find/replace/` substitution where find is:
- `^.*[ ]version="([^"]+)".*$` ignores characters from the beginning of line to a space followed by `version="`, the capture group `([^"]+)` captures one or more characters that follow that are not a `'"'` (i.e. the version number you want) and then `".*$` ignores from the closing `'"'` to end of line.
- the replace is `\1` which simply inserts the first bacreference (the stuff captured in the first capture group above), and
- `/p` then prints the result.

**Example Use/Output**

With your example in `file` you would have:

```
$ sed -E -n '/^<pkg-info/s/^.*[ ]version="([^"]+)".*$/\1/p' file
1.2.3
```

Comment: Breaks if there is a `\n` between `<pkg-info` and `version=`

Comment: @dawg 100% agreed, the explanation makes clear that `/^<pkg-info/` is used to locate that specific line. If the wanted version isn't in the line beginning with `/^<pkg-info/`, then it will not return the wanted version.

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Written and tested in GNU `awk`. Also as per experts advise a xml parsing tool would be best to parse xml file since OP is already using `awk` to parse OP's file so going with it.

```
awk '
/^<pkg-info/ && match($0,/[[:space:]]+version="([0-9]+\.){2}[0-9]+"[[:space:]]+/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  gsub(/^ +| +$/,"",val)
  print val
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                             ##Starting awk program from here.
/^<pkg-info/ && match($0,/[[:space:]]+version="([0-9]+\.){2}[0-9]+"[[:space:]]+/){
                                  ##Checking condition if line starts from <pkg-info AND matches mentioned regex.
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)   ##Creating val which is sub string of matched regex.
  gsub(/^ +| +$/,"",val)          ##Substituting starting and ending spaces with NULL in val.
  print val                       ##Printing val value here.
}
' Input_file                      ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: That looks quite nice as well, Good way to skin that cat!

Comment: Does not work if the XML has any `\n` between `pkg-info` and `version=`

Comment: @dawg, sure, that's why I had mentioned its clearly written as per shown samples only.

Answer (score 1):

What you have there is an [XML Element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Key_terminology) with an attribute=value combination you wish to get.

While you *could* have a simple `awk` or `sed` that will retrieve `1.2.3` from the one-line example you have, you really **should** use an [XML parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Pull_parsing). It will likely not work in the future if you don't.

While you have given the attributes all-on-one-line example of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<pkg-info overwrite-permissions="true" relocatable="false" identifier="com.application.something" version="1.2.3" format-version="2" generator-version="ABC" install-location="/Applications" auth="root">
</pkg-info>
```

The same data could just as easily be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<pkg-info overwrite-permissions="true" 
          relocatable="false" identifier="com.application.something" 
          version="1.2.3" format-version="2" 
          generator-version="ABC" install-location="/Applications" auth="root">
</pkg-info>
```

Or,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><pkg-info overwrite-permissions="true" relocatable="false" identifier="com.application.something" version="1.2.3" format-version="2" generator-version="ABC" install-location="/Applications"  auth="root"/>
```

and still be parsed as the same data. All three examples are valid XML but none of the awk or sed answers here handle any but the first example.

For XML, a `'\n'`, `' '`, `'\t'` and `'\r'` are all the same<sup>**1**</sup>  but to awk and sed those characters have very different meaning. To try and coerce a line oriented tool like awk or sed to deal with tag oriented data like XML is **extremely fragile**.

The best way to deal with this is to use an [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) query. The relevant query would be:

```
/pkg-info/@version
```

[DEMO](http://xpather.com/z38caC90)

Given `file` that has some valid form of XML as above, you can use one of these methods.

Here is a simple example in Ruby. Use [nokogiri](https://nokogiri.org) xml parser to parse with an xpath to the attribute of interest:

```
ruby -r nokogiri -e 'doc=Nokogiri::XML($<.read)
puts doc.xpath("/pkg-info").attribute("version").value' file
1.2.3
```

(You may need to install nokogiri with `gem install nokogiri` on your system...)

Or with [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/docs.php):

```
xml sel -t -v '/pkg-info/@version' file
1.2.3
```

If you have `XML::XPath` module installed with your Perl, (and most systems do) you also have a command line XPath query tool called `xpath`. You can do:

```
xpath -q -e '/pkg-info/@version' file
 version="1.2.3"
```

Then run that through `sed` to just get the value:

```
xpath -q -e '/pkg-info/@version' file | sed -E 's/[^"]*"([^"]*).*/\1/'
1.2.3
```

Note that an XML parser **will work** with the any legit version of your XML data. The other `sed` or `awk` solutions here will not.

---

And if your *wreally wreally wreally* want to use a regex, Perl is a better bet. This works with all three examples above:

```
perl -0777 -lnE 'say $1 if /(?:\s|>)<pkg-info[\s\S]*?\sversion="([^"]+)"/m' file
```

---

If you *hafta hafta hafta* have an `awk` you can set `RS-"^$"` which has the effect of reading the entire file in as one string then:

1. Find the point with `"<pkg-info "`.
2. Since these are attributes and not nested tags, there will be no `>` in the attribute section. But, no matter how the `<pkg-info` element is terminated, there must be a `>` to terminate it.
3. Now sub everything on either side of the `' version="` value with `""`
4. Print and profit.

This `awk` works with all my examples; HOWEVER, you really *should* use an XML parser.

```
awk -v RS="^$" '{ x=index($0, "<pkg-info ")
                  s=substr($0,x)
                  sub(/[^>]*\sversion="/,"", s)
                  sub(/".*/,"", s)
                  print s
                }' file
```

---

<sup>1</sup> So long as those characters are [insignificant whitespace](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/wang-whitespace.html), which they are in this example...

Answer (score 0):

**Awk** and XML are not the best of friends because **awk** is a regular expression driven line-based tool. XML is not a simple format that can be easily filtered with line based tools; so also, it is difficult to create a regular expression that can reliably match to all the ways XML can be presented.

To make sure we don't make a mistake, we leversge a state machine (a filter) that understands XML to transform it to something line-based that we can work with reliably. One such tool is **xml2** which provides a parseable "flat" output from XML.  Here is an example of the filtered result of your sample....

```
$ xml2 < some.xml
/pkg-info/@overwrite-permissions=true
/pkg-info/@relocatable=false
/pkg-info/@identifier=com.application.something
/pkg-info/@version=1.2.3
/pkg-info/@format-version=2
/pkg-info/@generator-version=ABC
/pkg-info/@install-location=/Applications
/pkg-info/@auth=root
```

After filtering the XML, it is trivial to create a reliable **awk** or **sed** filter to grab our output...  Here are a couple ideas:

```
$ xml2 < some.xml | awk -F= '$1 == "/pkg-info/@version" { print $2 }'
1.2.3
$ xml2 < some.xml | sed -e 's,^/pkg-info/@version=,,; t; d'
1.2.3
```